# sub_filter not working in nginx reverse-proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to put nginx as a reverse proxy in front of an app.  I seem to get most of the proxy_rewrite and sub_filter to work using the below config.

```
server {
  listen 8001;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app1:777/;

    proxy_redirect http://app1:777 http://$http_host;
    proxy_redirect http://app2:777 http://$http_host;

    sub_filter_types *;
    sub_filter http://app1:777 $http_host;
    sub_filter http://app2:777 $http_host;
    sub_filter_once off;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_buffering off;
  }
}
```

But when I watch the browser debug screen, I see all the GET requests use the proper outside hostname (localhost:8001), but I see a few OPTION calls that are using the inside DNS name (app1:777).

What did I miss?  I thought the sub_filter would catch that.

Thanks.